# Python Dictionary not getting updated correctly

Tags: python, dictionary

```
mydict = {}        
bufferID = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]    
physicalAddrList1 = [9,8]    
physicalAddrList2 = [10,11]    
addressToIdMap = {}
def Update_Dictionary(physicalAddrList,cmdId,opcode): 
    for address in physicalAddrList:
         list = GetBufferId()
         addressToIdMap[address] = list 
         mydict[cmdId,opcode] = addressToIdMap
def GetBufferId():
    list = []
    list.append([bufferID.pop(),25])
    return list 

Update_Dictionary(physicalAddrList1,1,0x01)    
Update_Dictionary(physicalAddrList2,2,0x02)      
print mydict
```

OutPut:

```
C:\Users\29213\Desktop> list4.py
{(1, 1): {8: [[25, 25]], 9: [[26, 25]], 10: [[24, 25]], 11: [[23, 25]]}, (2, 2): {8: [[25, 25]], 9: [[26, 25]], 10: [[24, 25]], 11: [[23, 25]]}}
```

Even though both function calls are made with different physical address list, both dictionary keys have all 4 physical address .
    Ideally output should be:

```
{(1, 1): {8: [[25, 25]], 9: [[26, 25]]}, (2, 2):{10: [[24, 25]], 11: [[23, 25]]}}
```

Comment: Sorry wrong statement!!!: Python Dictionary not getting updated correctly

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with the declaration `addressToIdMap = {}`. You declared it on the module level, so it's not cleared before you call your `Update_Dictionary` function the second time.

You need to move it inside `Update_Dictionary`

```
def Update_Dictionary(physicalAddrList,cmdId,opcode): 
    addressToIdMap = {}
    for address in physicalAddrList:
         list = GetBufferId()
         addressToIdMap[address] = list 
         mydict[cmdId,opcode] = addressToIdMap
```